# Extract month from ISO-8601 format date using R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, lubridate

I have a dataframe with `date` column (its data type is factor) in format as follows:

```
uid             date
<int>          <fctr>
2970134  2019-12-31T17:05:00Z           
2970204  2019-12-31T23:14:00Z           
2970345  2020-01-01T11:00:00Z
```

I've converted them to the format `2019-12-31T00:00:00+0800` with code below:

```
data$date <- format(as.POSIXct(data$date), format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

My question is I how to could I extract **month** from it? I tried with `format(as.POSIXct(data$date_single, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'),format='%m')` but it returns `NA`s. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small logic error. You take your input data and parse it -- so far, so good:

```
> v <- c("2019-12-31T17:05:00Z", "2019-12-31T23:14:00Z", "2020-01-01T11:00:00Z")
> pt <- as.POSIXct(v)
> pt
[1] "2019-12-31 CST" "2019-12-31 CST" "2020-01-01 CST"
>
```

Now that you have date(time) information, you can `format()` or `strftime()` as you like:

```
> strftime(pt, "%m")
[1] "12" "12" "01"
> strftime(pt, "%b")
[1] "Dec" "Dec" "Jan"
> strftime(pt, "%B")
[1] "December" "December" "January" 
>
```

Converting from `character` to `int` is also easy.  Note that all this was done with base R without any additional packages.

Comment: Thanks, is there an error in `strftime(as.POSIXct(test$date, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'), "%m")`? Why I assign format, it return `NA`s?

Comment: I showed you version that works that does not need a format.  That's good enough for me.  If you think you need to use a `format` string read the documentation carefully.  As I recall `%z` is (or was at a time) machine-depedent.  The upshot is: you are better off _not_ imposing a format unless you have to and understand it, and you are best of to stick with ISO8601 formats .  My [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) packages works with that philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(tidyverse)    
require(lubridate) # Package for date and time manipulation

data %>%  
  mutate(month = month(date))
```